# Return all values of nested arrays using string identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, underscore.js

Given an object `searchable`, is there a simple way of returning all the `id` values using `lodash` or `underscore.js` (or equivalent) where I can define the path to id?

```
const searchable = {
    things: [
        {
            id: 'thing-id-one',
            properties: [
                { id: 'd1-i1' },
                { id: 'd1-i2' },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'thing-id-two',
            properties: [
                { id: 'd2-i1' },
                { id: 'd2-i2' },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking to see if this is possible in a manner similar to how we can use `lodash.get` e.g. if we wanted to return the `things` array from `searchable` we could do

```
const things = _.get(searchable, 'things');
```

I can't seem to find anything similar in the documentation. I am looking for something
that could contain an implementation similar to:

```
_.<some_function>(searchable, 'things[].properties[].id')
```

**Note:** I am well aware of functions like Array.map etc and there are numerous ways of extracting the id property - it is this specific use case that I am trying to figure out, what library could support passing a path as a string like above or does lodash/underscore support such a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution using the package [jsonpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath)

```
const jp = require('jsonpath');
      
const result = jp.query(searchable, '$.things[*].properties[*].id')
console.log(result);

// outputs: [ 'd1-i1', 'd1-i2', 'd2-i1', 'd2-i2' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily in plain js

like this

```js
const searchable = {
    things: [
        {
            id: 'thing-id-one',
            properties: [
                { id: 'd1-i1' },
                { id: 'd1-i2' },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'thing-id-two',
            properties: [
                { id: 'd2-i1' },
                { id: 'd2-i2' },
            ]
        }
    ]
}

const search = (data, k) => {
  
  if(typeof data !== 'object'){
    return []
  }
  return Object.entries(data).flatMap(([key, value]) => key === k ? [value]: search(value, k))
}

console.log(search(searchable, 'id'))
```

Comment: I like the recursive algorithm, but I suspect the question is asking specifically how to target the `id`s of the `properties`.

Answer (score 0):

`_.map` and `_.flatten` together with [iteratee shorthands](https://underscorejs.org/#iteratee) let you expand nested properties. Every time you need to expand into an array, just chain another `map` and `flatten`:

```js
const searchable = {
    things: [
        {
            id: 'thing-id-one',
            properties: [
                { id: 'd1-i1' },
                { id: 'd1-i2' },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'thing-id-two',
            properties: [
                { id: 'd2-i1' },
                { id: 'd2-i2' },
            ]
        }
    ]
}

// Let's say the path is "things[].properties[].id"
const result = _.chain(searchable)
.get('things').map('properties').flatten()
.map('id').value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.4/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```